# Creating Pac-man scheme/racket coding - Vector conversion

Tags: vector, scheme, racket, rkt

Well, I'm trying to do a maze-game, Pac-man, I need creation and render of map, for this, I did a *"map of vectors"* with the different states that I need.

This is the code:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image 2htdp/universe
         (only-in racket/draw
                  read-bitmap))

(require math/matrix)
(require math/array)

(define CELL-SIZE 20)
(define E (rectangle CELL-SIZE CELL-SIZE "solid" "black")) 
(define D (circle 3  "solid" "YELLOW"))   
(define W (rectangle CELL-SIZE CELL-SIZE "solid" "blue")) 
(define C (rectangle CELL-SIZE CELL-SIZE "solid" "red"))

(define Initial-Map
  (vector (vector W W W W W W W W W W W W W)
          (vector W C D D D D D D D D D D W)
          (vector W D W D W W W W W D W D W)
          (vector W D W D W D D D W D W D W)
          (vector W D W D D D W D D D W D W)
          (vector W D W W D W W W D W W D W)
          (vector E D D D D D E D D D D D E)
          (vector W D W W D W W W D W W D W)
          (vector W D W D D D W D D D W D W)
          (vector W D W D W D W D W D W D W)
          (vector W D W D D D W D D D W D W)
          (vector W D W D W D D D W D W D W)
          (vector W D D C W D W D W D D D W)
          (vector W W W W W W W W W W W W W)))



(define EMPTY  (rectangle CELL-SIZE CELL-SIZE "solid" "black")) ; Empty
(define DOT  (circle 3  "solid" "white")) ; DOT
(define WALL (rectangle CELL-SIZE CELL-SIZE "solid" "blue"))  ; Wall


(define Scene (empty-scene 400 400 "black"))

(define (paintWorld mundo) (place-image  (vector*->matrix Initial-Map) 100 100 Scene))

(big-bang 4
;(on-key changePacmanM)
;(on-tick automaticMovePacman 0.2)
(to-draw paintWorld)
(state true)
(name "Pacman - Racket"))
```

**This is the problem**

**Initial-Map** is the map vector.
How can i render it for the big-bang creation universe function?

I tried to convert vector to matrix with **vector*->matrix** in order to pass it to `place-image`:

```
(place-image (vector*->matrix Initial-Map) 100 100 Scene)
```

But I get the following error:

> place-image: expects an image as first argument, given (mutable-array #[#[(object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) (object:image% ...)

Comment: How didn't it work? Can you describe that?

Comment: Sure, well... When i try to place matrix as image with "(place-image  (vector*->matrix Initial-Map) 100 100 Scene)"

i get this error : "place-image: expects an image as first argument, given (mutable-array #[#[(object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) (object:image% ...) "

Comment: Taken literally, `place-image` function requires the first formal argument to be an image, while it seems `vector*->matrix` creates a `matrix`, which looks like a 2d-array.

Comment: I need to create that "map" and render it like as an image, so... how can i do that?

Comment: Simply put, looks like you're providing a array of array of images. I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, but seems like functions like `rectangle` and `circle` create image object, not `vector`. For instance, if there were an `image` constructor function in this library, it might look like `(image (image W W W ... ))`.